# How to get gcm registration token using gcm gem in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement web push notifications in my rails app using [gcm](https://github.com/spacialdb/gcm) gem but i am not able to get the registration token provided by the user to store it into db for sending notification. Is there any solution to get the registration id in ruby client side?

Answer (score 0):

You can get registration token using the [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/). Google provides the Instance ID API to handle the creation and updating of registration tokens. To use this API, include `InstanceIDListenerService` in the manifest:

```
<service android:name="[.MyInstanceIDService]" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

[To obtain a token](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client#sample-register), call `instanceID.getToken`, providing the app server's sender ID and setting the scope to `GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE`. Do not call this method in the main thread; instead, use a service that extends `IntentService`

Check this [page](https://priyankvex.wordpress.com/2015/09/11/making-gcm-client-in-android-and-application-server-in-ruby-on-rails/comment-page-1/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `registration_token` from android/ios application.

In android app you can get `registration_token` by using ..

```
gcm_instance_id = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
registration_token = gcm_instance_id.register(PROJECT_NUMBER);
```

You can find `PROJECT_NUMBER` from https://console.developers.google.com/

Then you can send this `registration_token` to rails api and store it into database..

Thanks